Title is not showing when uploading a video to TikTok via api
I am creating videos on TikTok using their API. With the video, I also provide a title. The video is showing up in my Inbox for approval as expected, but the title is not showing. Instead I only get a HashTag of the name of the App I am using.
I checked the code a few times and made sure the json structure is correct. What am I missing?
 return await fetch('https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/inbox/video/init/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            post_info: {
                privacy_level: 'PUBLIC_TO_EVERYONE',
                title: "Hello #world",
            },
            source_info: {
                source: 'PULL_FROM_URL',
                video_url: `THE VIDEO URL`
            }
        })
    })


I think your body might be ignored. Did you tried cors mode? Does it work from terminal (via CURL as is in documentation)? Does this answer your question? Unable to fetch POST without no-cors in header

It doesn't work on curl as well. In general, the post itself works. The video is shown as I said in my post, but the title is not shown.
